# How can i create the json object on python?

Tags: python, json

I tried to create a json object but I made a mistake somewhere. I'm getting some data on CSV file (center is string, lat and lng are float).

My codes:

```
data = []
data.append({
    'id': 'id',
    'is_city': false,
    'name': center,
    'county': center,
    'cluster': i,
    'cluster2': i,
    'avaible': true,
    'is_deleted': false,
    'coordinates': ('{%s,%s}' %(lat,lng))
})
json_data = json.dumps(data)
print json_data
```

It goes with this:

```
[{
    "county": "County", 
    "is_city": false, 
    "is_deleted": false, 
    "name": "name", 
    "cluster": 99, 
    "cluster2": 99, 
    "id": "id", 
    "coordinates": "{41.0063945,28.9048234}", 
    "avaible": true
}]
```

That's I want:

```
{ 
    "id" : "id",
    "is_city" : false,
    "name" : "name", 
    "county" : "county",
    "cluster" : 99,
    "cluster2" : 99,
    "coordinates" : [
        41.0870185, 
        29.0235126
    ], 
    "available" : true, 
    "isDeleted" : false, 
}
```

Comment: First step would be to correct the typos. Then explain to me how and why `'id'` should change to `'_id'`. Next, just dump the dictionary without appending it to a list first. Then tell me why you expect a string (the result of your string formatting) to become a list. Finally, I have a hunch that you are concerned about the order, in which case you need to read about python dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for help. 
As you see, i'm very new on python. I get "id, name and county" from my csv file so i write just their names. Order is not important that much. Coordinates is most important thing for me. That's the one actually i made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `coordinates` to be a string of the specified format.  There is no way `json` can encode that as a list; you are saying one thing when you want another.

Similarly, if you don't want the top-level dictionary to be the only element in a list, don't define it to be an element in a list.

```
data = {
    'id': 'id',
    'is_city': false,
    'name': name,
    'county': county,
    'cluster': i,
    'cluster2': i,
    'available': true,
    'is_deleted': false,
    'coordinates': [lat, lng]
}
```

I don't know how you defined `center`, or how you expected it to have the value `'name'` and the value `'county'` at basically the same time.  I have declared two new variables to hold these values; you will need to adapt your code to take care of this detail.  I also fixed the typo in "available" where apparently you expected Python to somehow take care of this.

Comment: It helps much. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pprint to make pretty printing at python, but it should be applied on object not string.
At your case json_data is a string that represents a JSON object, so you need to load it back to be an object when you try to pprint it, (or to use the data variable itself since it already contains this JSON object in your example)

for example try to run:
pprint.pprint(json.loads(json_data))